# how can i use Conditional Operator in react-native?? this error occure

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-native

native and i want to use Conditional Operator in components

but when i try to use Conditional Operator in react-native this errro occure

this my code

```
            import React from 'react';
            import styled from 'styled-components/native';
            import {FlatList} from 'react-native';
            import {useSelector,useDispatch} from 'react-redux';

            const Container = styled.View`

            `;

            const Hey = styled.Text`

            `;

            const Food = ({navigation}) => {

                const {cookUp} = useSelector((state) => state.post);


                console.log("cookUp:",cookUp);
            

                return (
                    {cookUp ? (
                <FlatList
                data={cookUp}
                keyExtractor={(item) => String(item.id)}
                // keyExtractor={(item, index) => {
                //     return `${index}`;
                // }}
            renderItem={({item}) => (
                <Hey>
                    {item.name}
                </Hey>
            )}
                />
                    ) : (<Hey>hi</Hey>)

            }
            
                );
            };

            export default Food;
```

this error ocuure

[image]

i don't know how can i fix... how can i do that?

Comment: Curly braces are for dynamic values *inside* JSX tags. The ternary operator is outside the tags in this case, so curly braces aren't needed. Remove the outermost curly braces (the ones opening before `cookup ? ....`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a try by removing the curly brackets in the return functions.

```
return (
    cookUp ? (
        <FlatList
            data={cookUp}
            keyExtractor={(item) => String(item.id)}
            // keyExtractor={(item, index) => {
            //     return `${index}`;
            // }}
            renderItem={({item}) => (
            <Hey>
                {item.name}
            </Hey>
            )}
        />
    ) :
        (<Hey>hi</Hey>)
);
```